# inspect.isgeneratorfunction() returns wrong results

Tags: python-3.x, generator, code-inspection

I've been using `inspect.isgeneratorfunction` on my code successfully. Here's a simple example:

```py
def f():
    for _ in range(5):
        yield "Hello World!"
```

`inspect.isgeneratorfunction(f)`, `inspect.isgeneratorfunction(blah.f)` (when I store `f` in `blah.py`), and `inspect.isgeneratorfunction(foo.f)` (when `blah` is imported as `foo`), among others, all correctly return `True` as expected.

However, when I apply this to the following function from `networkx`, which has a similar structure, results are wrong: `inspect.isgeneratorfunction(networkx.biconnected_components)` returns `False`.

```py
@not_implemented_for("directed")
def biconnected_components(G):
    """(docstring trimmed)"""
    for comp in _biconnected_dfs(G, components=True):
        yield set(chain.from_iterable(comp))
```

What am I missing?

Possibly relevant:

- I'm using Python 3.11.2 and networkx 2.8.8
- `networkx.biconnected_components` actually points to `networkx.algorithms.components.biconnected.biconnected_components`